# Can Google natural language be use for spell check and grammar check

Tags: google-cloud-nl

Can Google Cloud Natural Language API be used for spell check and grammar check?
Could it be a good alternative to LanguageTool.org?
If it is possible, how can it be done?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/

Answer (score 1):

As @AngusTay explained in his answer, Google Cloud Natural Language API can perform syntax analysis to identify how a sentence is structured and classify its components, among other features, however it does not provide a grammar and spelling check.

Follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/basics) to understand what can be done using the Natural Language API. Basically, the API includes:

- Sentiment analysis to identify the emotional opinion within the text.
- Entity analysis to provide information about different entities present in the sentence.
- Entity sentiment analysis to identify emotional opinions about the entities present in the sentence.
- Syntactic analysis to extract linguistic information from all the words and tokens in a sentence.
- Content classification to identify the words and classify them according to different categories.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Google Cloud NL does not provide spell check and grammar check.
It does analysis on the sentences, giving info with the machine learning algorithm

- prediction: sentiment analysis
- sentence structure: Syntax analysis
- Entity info: Entities analysis

So it doesn't do the same thing as language tool (which checks spelling and grammar).